# Creating a Facebook ad creative from an app in development mode

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to create an ad creative in Facebook from my test app with the following request (pretty much taken from the Python SDK Docs [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/blob/master/examples/docs/adgroup.py#L55)):

```
Message: Call was not successful
Method:  POST
Path:     https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/act_somenumber/adcreatives
Params:  {'object_story_spec': '{"link_data":{"caption":"www.example.com","image_hash":"existing_hash","link":"http://example.com","message":"try it out"},"page_id":"some_page_id"}', 'name': 'AdCreative for Link Ad'}
```

However, I get the following response:

```
Status:  500
Response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 100,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_subcode": 1885183,
    "error_user_msg": "Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode. It must be in public to create this ad.",
    "error_user_title": "Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode",
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "FacebookApiException"
  }
}
```

Now, I've seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003816/cant-create-facebook-ad-creative-with-a-facebook-app-in-a-development-mode), which states:

> If you want to create ads from an app which is in development mode, this is possible, but the post you're going to promote must have been created by an app which isn't in development mode - i.e if your app is in development mode it's OK provided you're promoting existing page posts from a page's /promotable_posts endpoint and the app that created those posts is not itself in development mode

I'm not trying to create an ad; I'm merely trying to create an ad creative and then later update the ad to use that creative. What is the correct way of creating a new creative with link data from a development app? I have no problem creating ad creatives that correspond to right hand column ads, it's the newsfeed / feeds ads whose objectives are  "Website Clicks". The ad in question was actually created through the ad manager, not through an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work-around is simply to create a dummy app and set it publicly visible.