# Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode. It must be in public to create this ad in facebook advertising

Tags: facebook-node-sdk

I am trying to do ad for `messenger_sponsored_message` in `fb` but getting error like this:

```
Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode. It must be in public to create this ad.
```

Comment: ["The work-around is simply to create a dummy app and set it publicly visible."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213613/creating-a-facebook-ad-creative-from-an-app-in-development-mode) This means that you need to go to your app dashboard (https://developers.facebook.com/apps), select the App that you are working on and set to public (there is a toggle button on top-right set on Off. You need to turn it On).