# Unable to create ad_creative, advert & leadgen form in facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

Background;
We are currently developing a facebook application, that will allow us to publish advertisements which are basically leadgen forms, that on submission will send the data back to the our dedicated crm. Now upon creating the application we needed manage_pages, ad_management, lead_retreival & ad_read permissions.

Problem(s);
We got our manage_pages permission approved and the real confusion started when we came to the ads_management permission & the rest of the permissions. For these permissions we created a advertisement sandbox account then with it we were able to create a ads campaign, after it we were able to create adsets as well, then we hit dead end as we were unable to create ads creative or the ads as well. Every time we tried it threw this error;

"Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode. It must be in public to create this ad"

A flow we followed to try and work around this issue;

First we tried to create ad directly by, bypassing the creation of ad creative step & giving the
advert creative id by hard quoting it into our code. This hard quoted id belonged to already created advert creative for the primary page we had associated to our sand box account. But then it gave creative id is not valid.

Then we made our application live but that expired our sandbox ad account tokens.

Then on the next flow we were not able to get dummy application solution suggested here;

[Creating a Facebook ad creative from an app in development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213613/creating-a-facebook-ad-creative-from-an-app-in-development-mode?rq=1)

After the first workflow, we tried to be more specific with our use case and tried to create lead forms with graph api which we would have associated with an advertisement creative. The credentials we used here belong to the sandbox account and the flow we followed for this can be found at this link below;

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/create

But we were unable to get past the first step of creating a lead form, which threw an error of this;

http://prntscr.com/p8puv0

If we did not give private policy url then it gave us the error of this;

"Either legal_content_id or privacy_policy is required to be specified to create a LeadGen form"

After this we tried for the legal content id, it did not give us one, as facebook stopped support for it in april 2019.

Questions;

> How can we submit for the ads_management, lead_retrival, ads_read permssion if we can't show demonstration with our sandbox account with this issue of ads creative step?
>
> Any suggestion to what are we missing in leadgenform creation process? The very reason we got this flow before our ads_management permission approval is basically something that can reflect our use case to facebook so that they activate advertisement permission for us.

Apologies for;
If it is a long post
If this is beginner level question

Cheers, thank you in advance and eagerly looking forward for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fumbling around, myself. Official FB docs germane to this seem to be 404 ATM.

Try...

`privacy_policy={url: 'https://redacted.com/privacypolicy', link_text: 'Our_Private_Policy'}`

...instead of:

`privacy_policy=[{url: 'https://redacted.com/privacypolicy'}, {link_text: 'Our_Private_Policy'}]`

Worked for me. (The clue was 'Invalid keys "0, 1" were found in param "privacy_policy"'.)

Comment: TRL thanks man, it has been 20 days plus since i posted to facebook community, no response was recorded there, But damn I was lucky to find you and your answer. For the sake of clarity for those that are in this situation as i was i would also like to add that my facebook review was also accepted for advertisement managment, i showed them ads campaign creation step, adset creation step and then for advertisement creative step i just showed them the error that i was facing mentioned above. They were kind enough to accept the review for it. Peace